# Know if usercontrols finished loading with data in Silverlight 4

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have a navigation page in which i am loading multiple user controls with datagrids at runtime. These datagrids in usercontrol get loaded by WCF obviously. I have a BusyIndicator in Parent control and need to find out if usercontrols have finished loading data from WCF so that i can set IsBusy property of BusyIndicator to false.
 How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do this in the asynchronous call back of the method that retrieves the data for the controls.  For example, in a ViewModel you may have the following code (this isn't working code...just an example):

```
private bool _inProgress = true;

public bool InProgress
{
     get { return _inProgress; }
     set
            {
                if (_inProgress != value)
                {
                    _inProgress = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => InProgress);
                }
     }
}

public void GetData()
{
InProgress = true;
_wcfClient = myWCFDataClient;
_wcfClient.GetDataCompleted += _wcfClient_GetDataCompleted;
_wcfClient.GetDataAsync();
}

//Async callback
protected void _wcfClient_GetDataCompleted(object sender, MyCustomEventArgs e)
{
InProgress = false;
}
```

Your BusyIndicator in the view would need binding to the InProgress property of the ViewModel.  If you have multiple methods being called by multiple controls you may want to look at some advanced async patterns.  See my post here for some ideas: [Any good async workflow patterns for C# 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529066/any-good-async-workflow-patterns-for-c-sharp-4/6531822#6531822).  Not sure what version of C# you are using.  The link to my previous post was before the release of version 4.5.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my BusyIndicator is not in User control. Its in the Navigation Page control which is holding lot of User controls. I need to cascadethe value from user control to navigation page(parent) when user control finished loading data.

Comment: Do all of your user controls use the same ViewModel?  Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using MVVM architecture. Its all in code behind. I have navigation page in which there are 2 user controls loaded from wcf .I have BusyIndicator in navigation page. I need to find if user controls finished loading. I tried using

Comment: Application.Current.RootVisual to get the parent in user control but its null